# Getting E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) error when trying to play a video from given URL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

I'm building and app that allows user to check out new movies and their trailers, data is queried from imdb API

Here is my code segment that calls the `VideoView`

```
private fun setTrailer(trailer: Trailer){
        val trailerPlayer = view?.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.trailerView)
        trailerPlayer?.setMediaController(MediaController(this.context))
        trailerPlayer?.setVideoPath(trailer.trailerUrl)
        trailerPlayer?.requestFocus()
        trailerPlayer?.start()
    }
```

I have it put in the `onCreateView` as such

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //some other functions
        getMovieTrailer()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_detail_layout, container, false)
    }
```

Here is the URL that I get from the API

[Link 1](https://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi2959588889/imdb/embed)

permission to use internet is granted, my sdk is 26 and both the links are https

I Keep getting error message `E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)` and a dialog that says "Can't play this video"

I've also tried using this link but got the same error

[Link 2](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi2959588889)

I've found some answers but none have worked so far

Any tip is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

trailerPlayer?.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(trailer.trailerUrl))

Comment: I tried that too, still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //some other functions
    
    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_detail_layout, container, false)
getMovieTrailer()
return view
}
```

Comment: The problem persists with the same error message, but I appreciate the help

Comment: share the class